# While Loops with functions and states in python

Tags: python, arrays, pygame

I have a school project I've been religiously trying to get working. I've tried indenting, De-denting, defining local and global variables, and even asking my teacher. To no avail. What i want to happen while in state 3, is when you click on a button, it changes the state within the function and once the loop finishes, the state changes and therefore so does the while loop.

```
def buttonCollide():
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Level 1", smallText)
textRect.center = (200,250)
screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
    if 170+100 > mouse[0] > 130 and 270+50 > mouse[1] > 170: ### BUTTON 1
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,selected_white,(200,250),70,0)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Level 1", smallText)
        textRect.center = (200,250)
        screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
        if 170+100 > mouse[0] > 130 and 270+50 > mouse[1] > 200 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        state = 4

while state == 3:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            quit()
    screen.fill(dark_blue)
    drawMenu()
    buttonCollide()
    pygame.display.update()
```

It should switch to state 4 after this loop exits ButtonCollide(), but for some reason it constantly sets the state back to 3 after it exits the function.

Comment: please fix you code snippet indentation

Comment: " I've been religiously trying to get working. I've tried indenting, De-denting, defining local and global variables" => actually this looks mostly like you tried "programming by accident" (AKA "programming by permutations") : tryning anything whithout really understanding what you were doing until it would magically "start working".

Comment: Thanks for you feedback but this is my first year coding. Thanks for the negativity.

Comment: I'm sorry you take it as "negative", the point was to help you realize you won't learn much that way. It's ok to try out things to understand how they work, but then you have to do it in a very systematic way (basing your tests on what you think you understood from the manual, keeping each variation and it's results, etc), preferably with a toy example (you don't need the whole pygame stuff here).

Answer (score 1):

You have issues with scope, as state variable in the script and in function do not share same scope.
Add `global state` right after the line `def buttonCollide():`.

Like

```
def buttonCollide():
   global state
   ...
```

Comment: A better solution would be to have `buttonCollide()` return a new state value and let the caller update the state. Mutable globals are evil, really.

Comment: I was aiming for the `least lines to edit` solution, that ^ is for sure better option to do @brunodesthuilliers